# Can a child ride in a Grab or Taxi without a child seat in Malaysia and Singapore?

Tags: singapore, malaysia

I'm going to be travelling in Singapore and Malaysia (KL and Penang) with two young kids. I'm trying to figure out the best modes of transportation to get around.

Just wondering, what is the policy for Grab or taxis in terms of child seats? In many countries, taxis are exempt from child restraint policy.

Answer (score 4):

I only know the situation in **Singapore**, as I have used both taxis and Grab for getting around with a baby.

The [basic rule](https://sso.agc.gov.sg/SL/RTA1961-S688-2011?DocDate=20111227) is: any person with a height of below 1.35 metres must be seated in a child restraint or a booster seat. There is however an [exemption for taxis](https://www.police.gov.sg/resources/traffic-matters/already-have-a-licence/revised-seat-belt-rules-faqs#content), where children are allowed on the rear seat without a child restraint.

This exemption [does not apply](https://www.sassymamasg.com/car-safety-in-singapore-taxis-laws-car-seats-boosters/) to private hire vehicles such as Grab though. In that case you have the option of bringing along your own car seat, or use the special  [Grab Family](https://www.grab.com/sg/family/) option, that comes with two sizes of car seat. There's an extra charge of $5 or $2 depending on the age of the child. I've never actually used this option, so I'm not sure how well it works in practice.